# How can i pass a c# variable in CommandName attribute in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, variables

### How can i pass a c# variable in CommandName attribute in aspx page

I wanna pass the idCategory inside the CommandName attribute, when i try to do it 
with an html element like div or any it works, but with
the asp.net element like asp:button doesn't.
is there any way to solve that! and Thanks!

```cs
<tbody ID="tbody">
<% 
   DAL.InventoryEntities Ie = new DAL.InventoryEntities();
   foreach (DAL.Category category in Ie.Categories) { 
%>

  <tr>
    <td><%: category.idCategory %></td>
    <td><%: category.name %></td>
    <td>
      <asp:LinkButton runat="server" 
                      CommandName='<%= category.idCategory %>'
                      CssClass="btn btn-info btn-block btn-md" 
                      Text="Select" 
                      OnCommand="Select_Command"></asp:LinkButton>
      </td>
  </tr>

<% } %>
</tbody>

> code behind:

protected void Select_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Hello " + e.CommandName);
}

output: Hello <%= category.idCategory %>
```

Comment: try to replace ``=`` by ``#`` in ``CommandName='<%= category.idCategory %>'``

Comment: > compliaton error                                                                                      <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName='<%# category.idCategory %>' CssClass="btn btn-info btn-block btn-md" Text="Select" OnCommand="Select_Command"></asp:LinkButton>

Answer (score 0):

Use a repeater and bind it from code behind. Use CommandArgument instead of CommandName, if you are binding the category id.

**aspx page**

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" OnInit="rpt_Init" ItemType="DAL.Category">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%# Item.idCategory %></td>
                        <td><%# Item.name %></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server"
                                CommandArgument="<%# Item.idCategory %>"
                                CssClass="btn btn-info btn-block btn-md"
                                Text="Select"
                                OnCommand="Select_Command"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

**code behind**

```
protected void rpt_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DAL.InventoryEntities Ie = new DAL.InventoryEntities();
   rpt.DataSource = Ie.Categories;
   rpt.DataBind();
}

protected void Select_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
   Response.Write("Hello " + e.CommandArgument);
}
```

Note: if you want to access Binding context in command handler, I suggest you to use OnItemCommand on repeater instead of OnCommand on button. You'll be able then to access current Item from event handler parameter:
[image]